# How to optimize this Postgres count query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT count(*) 
FROM "businesses" 
WHERE (
    source = 'facebook' 
    OR EXISTS( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM provider_business_map pbm 
        WHERE 
            pbm.hotstepper_business_id=businesses.id 
            AND pbm.provider_name='facebook' 
    )
);
PLAN                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=233538965.74..233538965.75 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=116169.720..116169.721 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on businesses  (cost=0.00..233521096.48 rows=7147706 width=0) (actual time=11.284..116165.646 rows=3693 loops=1)
         Filter: (((source)::text = 'facebook'::text) OR (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Index Scan using idx_provider_hotstepper_business on provider_business_map pbm  (cost=0.00..16.29 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
                 Index Cond: (((provider_name)::text = 'facebook'::text) AND (hotstepper_business_id = businesses.id))
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Index Scan using idx_provider_hotstepper_business on provider_business_map pbm  (cost=0.00..16.28 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.045..5.685 rows=3858 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: ((provider_name)::text = 'facebook'::text)
 Total runtime: 116169.820 ms
(10 rows)
```

This query takes over a minute and it's doing a count that results in ~3000.  It seems the bottleneck is the sequential scan but I'm not sure what index I would need on the database to optimize this.  It's also worth noting that I haven't tuned postgres so if there's any tuning that would help it may be worth considering.  Although my DB is 15GB and I don't plan on trying to fit all of that in memory anytime soon so I'm not sure changing RAM related values would help a lot.

Comment: On PostgreSQL version .... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR is notorious for lousy performance. Try splitting it into a union of two completely separate queries on the two tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM businesses 
    WHERE source = 'facebook'
    UNION   -- union makes the ids unique in the result
    SELECT hotstepper_business_id
    FROM provider_business_map
    WHERE provider_name = 'facebook'
    AND hotstepper_business_id IS NOT NULL
) x
```

If `hotstepper_business_id` can not be null, you may remove the line

```
AND hotstepper_business_id IS NOT NULL
```

---

If you want the whole business row, you'd could simply wrap the above query with an `IN (...)`:

```
SELECT * FROM businesses
WHERE ID IN (
    -- above inner query
)
```

But a much better performing query would be to modify the above query use use a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM businesses 
WHERE source = 'facebook'
UNION
SELECT b.*
FROM provider_business_map m
JOIN businesses b
  ON b.id = m.hotstepper_business_id
WHERE provider_name = 'facebook'
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense because I was getting great performance doing this in code - pull both sets into an array and dedup but it seemed like I should be solving something like that on the DB level.  Thank you!

Comment: Would my query make better sense if I wasn't doing the count though?  Or should I use your methodology and do ```SELECT * from businesses where businesses.id IN ( YOUR SUBQUERY )```

Comment: Try to avoid `where id in (subquery)` - they don't perform well.  See edited answer for the fastest way to get all business rows

Answer (score 1):

I'd at least *try* rewriting the dependent subquery as;

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.*)
FROM businesses b
LEFT JOIN provider_business_map pbm
  ON b.id=pbm.hotstepper_business_id
WHERE b.source = 'facebook'
  OR pbm.provider_name = 'facebook';
```

Unless I'm mis-reading something, an index on `businesses.id` exists, but make sure there are also indexes on `provider_business_map.hotstepper_business_id`, `businesses.source` and `provider_business_map.provider_name` for best performance.

Comment: Wouldn't a multicolumn index on ```pbm.provider_name``` and ```pbm.hotstepper_business_id``` have the best performance? I have ```idx_provider_hotstepper_business" btree (provider_name, hotstepper_business_id)```

Comment: @wachutu Only `hotstepper_business_id` is always used, so you'll probably want to reverse that to `btree (hotstepper_business_id, provider_name)` for this query to run fast.

Comment: Not following you.  The cardinality is much lower on provider_name so shouldn't I have the multicolumn index limit by that first?  Would Postgres not limit the provider_business_map set that it checks first by the provider_name?  It seems like that would be the best way to limit the number of rows being checked on provider_business_map

Comment: Hm, yes, I mis-read the schema from the query when commenting, placing source in pbm which is quite different. You're probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
create index index_name on businesses(source);
```

Since there 3,693 rows matches in more than 7 million rows it will probably use the index. Do not forget to

```
analyse businesses;
```